# SQL: record duplication when i use two different INNER JOIN with 3 total tables

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I would like to use 2 `INNER JOIN` at the same time and join 3 tables: `Match_Next`, `Match_Results` and `MyTest`. My goal is to get, via a loop and a dictionary, the `score_home` of `away_club` in a dictionary list. Problems arise when i use the second `INNER JOIN`, because the score_homes are duplicated 3 or 4 times in the list.

Initially, when i join the `Match_Next` table together with the `Match_Results` table, using `home_club` as the match, everything is ok. In fact, for example, Chicago has `score_home = (0, 0, 1, 2)`.

```
x = cur.execute('''SELECT Match_Next.home_club||" VS "||Match_Next.away_club,
                          Match_Next.turn, Match_Results.score_home 
                   FROM Match_Next
                   INNER JOIN Match_Results ON Match_Next.home_club = Match_Results.home_club''')
```

**PROBLEM:** is when I insert the second `INNER JOIN`, because instead of `score_home = (0, 0, 1, 2)`, i get something similar to `score_home = (0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2)`.

**WHAT RESULT DO I WANT?:** To the above code, i want to add the second `INNER JOIN` to add columns `A` and `B` of the `MyTest` table. But I want to print (for example) Chicago `score_home = (0, 0, 1, 2)` and not the duplicate values that i mistakenly get when i use the second INNER JOIN. So I use `home_club` as a match here too and write: `INNER JOIN MyTest ON Match_Next.team_home = MyTest.team_home`

```
x = cur.execute('''SELECT Match_Next.home_club||" VS "||Match_Next.away_club,
                          Match_Next.turn, Match_Results.score_home,
                          MyTest.A, MyTest.B
                   FROM Match_Next
                   INNER JOIN Match_Results ON Match_Next.home_club = Match_Results.home_club
                   INNER JOIN MyTest ON Match_Next.home_club = MyTest.home_club''')
```

however, the values are mistakenly duplicated as shown above. How can i solve this problem?

**NOTE** that I also tried using `DISTINCT`, but it's not the right solution, because for example score_home = (0, 0, 1, 2) becomes `(0,1,2)` and that's not what I'm looking for.

I show you the database tables and an example of its data:

The `Match_Next` table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Match_Next" (
"Id" INTEGER,
"turn" INTEGER,
"home_club" INTEGER,
"away_club" INTEGER,
"score_home" NUMERIC,
"score_away" NUMERIC,
PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

INSERT INTO Match_Next
  (`turn`, `home_club`, `away_club`, `score_home`, `score_away`)
VALUES
  ('8', 'Chicago', 'Lakers', '?', '?'),
  ('8', 'Minnesota', 'Dallas', '?', '?');
```

The `Match_Results` table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Match_Results" (
    "Id" INTEGER,
    "turn" INTEGER,
    "home_club" INTEGER,
    "away_club" INTEGER,
    "score_home" NUMERIC,
    "score_away" NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
    );

INSERT INTO Match_Results
  (`turn`, `home_club`, `away_club`, `score_home`, `score_away`)
VALUES
  ('7', 'Chicago', 'New York', '2', '1'),
  ('7', 'Dallas', 'Indiana', '1', '0'),
  ('6', 'Milwaukee', 'Dallas', '0', '2'),
  ('6', 'Detroit', 'Chicago', '3', '2'),
  ('5', 'Chicago', 'Brooklyn', '1', '4'),
  ('5', 'Dallas', 'Memphis Gr', '2','3'),
  ('4', 'Chicago', 'Oklahoma', '0', '2'),
  ('4', 'Golden State', 'Dallas', '3', '1'),
  ('3', 'Dallas', 'Phoenix', '3', '0'),
  ('3', 'San Antonio', 'Chicago', '4', '1'),
  ('2', 'Chicago', 'Detroit', '0', '2'),
  ('2', 'Toronto', 'Dallas', '1', '3'),
  ('1', 'Dallas', 'Boston', '2', '1'),
  ('1', 'Indiana', 'Chicago', '2', '0')
```

The `MyTest` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTest" (
"Id" INTEGER,
"turn" INTEGER,
"home_club" INTEGER,
"away_club" INTEGER,
"score_home" NUMERIC,
"score_away" NUMERIC,
"A" NUMERIC,
"B" NUMERIC,
PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

INSERT INTO MyTest
  (`turn`, `home_club`, `away_club`, `score_home`, `score_away`, `A`, `B`)
VALUES
  ('7', 'Chicago', 'New York', '2', '1', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('7', 'Dallas', 'Indiana', '1', '0', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('6', 'Milwaukee', 'Dallas', '0', '2', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('6', 'Detroit', 'Chicago', '3', '2', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('5', 'Chicago', 'Brooklyn', '1', '4', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('5', 'Dallas', 'Memphis Gr', '2','3', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('4', 'Chicago', 'Oklahoma', '0', '2', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('4', 'Golden State', 'Dallas', '3', '1', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('3', 'Dallas', 'Phoenix', '3', '0', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('3', 'San Antonio', 'Chicago', '4', '1', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('2', 'Chicago', 'Detroit', '0', '2', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('2', 'Toronto', 'Dallas', '1', '3', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('1', 'Dallas', 'Boston', '2', '1', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'), 
  ('1', 'Indiana', 'Chicago', '2', '0', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb')
```

Comment: please add also the data taht would produce your wanted result

Comment: @nbk I updated and added the data. I hope you can help me

Comment: that doesn't work see https://dbfiddle.uk/Oogy2dq-

Comment: @nbk I do not understand. Are you getting a SQL error? For example purposes, I wrote the various Insert Into manually. I probably wrote them wrong. What's wrong?

Comment: @nbk Maybe I shouldn't have written the ID (the first numbers)

Comment: please take the fiddle and adept to fit your descrion but as sample table Match_Next the is no column with text but you have chicago in yoiur insert which doesn't work

Comment: @nbk I'm writing again because I pasted the wrong new link  https://dbfiddle.uk/v_eAlxQb  .Now everything is ok in dbfiddle. The text " #empty, inside is "?" in Match_Next was just a comment for informational purposes. It can be deleted. It seemed intuitive to me. Also there were some wrong commas. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Match_results` and `MyTest` tables seem very similar. You can JOIN these tables by similar columns and take columns A and B from MyTest table.
See example:

```
SELECT   Match_Next.home_club||'-'||Match_Next.away_club,
    Match_Next.turn, Match_Results.score_home,
    MyTest.A, MyTest.B
FROM Match_Next
inner JOIN Match_Results ON Match_Next.home_club = Match_Results.home_club
inner JOIN MyTest 
  ON Match_Results.home_club = MyTest.home_club 
 and Match_Results.away_club = MyTest.away_club
  ;
```

[Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XLK23J2v)

Upd1. About difference of JOIN with 1 or 2 conditions.
Let's take for example a small amount of data from your set:

```
-- 1 row in Match_Next
INSERT INTO Match_Next (`turn`, `home_club`, `away_club`, `score_home`, `score_away`)
VALUES
  ('8', 'Chicago', 'Lakers', '?', '?')
-- 2 rows in MAtch_Results
INSERT INTO Match_Results
  (`turn`, `home_club`, `away_club`, `score_home`, `score_away`)
VALUES

  ('7', 'Chicago', 'New York', '2', '1'),
  ('5', 'Chicago', 'Brooklyn', '1', '4')
;
-- and 2 rows in MyTest
INSERT INTO MyTest
  (`turn`, `home_club`, `away_club`, `score_home`, `score_away`, `A`, `B`)
VALUES
  ('7', 'Chicago', 'New York', '2', '1', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb'),
  ('5', 'Chicago', 'Brooklyn', '1', '4', 'example_aaa', 'example_bbb') ;
;
```

Query with booth conditions

```
SELECT  Match_Next.home_club||'-'||Match_Next.away_club as Match_next_clubs,
   Match_Results.home_club as Results_home_club
  ,Match_Results.away_club as Results_away_club
  ,MyTest.home_club as MyTest_home_club
  ,MyTest.away_club as MyTest_away_club
FROM Match_Next
inner JOIN Match_Results ON Match_Next.home_club = Match_Results.home_club
inner JOIN MyTest ON Match_Results.home_club = MyTest.home_club 
   and Match_Results.away_club = MyTest.away_club
 ;
```

gets result

| Match_next_clubs | Results_home_club | Results_away_club | MyTest_home_club | MyTest_away_club |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago-Lakers | Chicago | Brooklyn | Chicago | Brooklyn |
| Chicago-Lakers | Chicago | New York | Chicago | New York |

Query with 1 conditions

```
SELECT  Match_Next.home_club||'-'||Match_Next.away_club as Match_next_clubs,
   Match_Results.home_club as Results_home_club
  ,Match_Results.away_club as Results_away_club
  ,MyTest.home_club as MyTest_home_club
  ,MyTest.away_club as MyTest_away_club
FROM Match_Next
inner JOIN Match_Results ON Match_Next.home_club = Match_Results.home_club
inner JOIN MyTest ON Match_Results.home_club = MyTest.home_club 
 -- second condition is commented
 --  and Match_Results.away_club = MyTest.away_club
 ;
```

gets result

| Match_next_clubs | Results_home_club | Results_away_club | MyTest_home_club | MyTest_away_club |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago-Lakers | Chicago | Brooklyn | Chicago | Brooklyn |
| Chicago-Lakers | Chicago | Brooklyn | Chicago | New York |
| Chicago-Lakers | Chicago | New York | Chicago | Brooklyn |
| Chicago-Lakers | Chicago | New York | Chicago | New York |

We do not take into account the comparison like 'Brooklyn'<>'New York'.

In first case   (second row)
'Chicago'=Chicago'  - true
'Brooklyn'='New York' - false
condition=(true & false)=false  -row skipped from output

In next  case
'Chicago'=Chicago'  - true (and 'Brooklyn'='New York' - do not check)
condition=(true )=true  -row included to output.

Why JOIN Match_Results and MyTest , instead Match_Next and MyTest - you can write for you and us - what means this join for your task, what's the point of it.
I can only guess from the structure of the tables;)

Comment: Who knows why they gave you a negative rating if the code is correct. I'm no SQL expert (except for basic stuff), but your code always right. I tested your code and it works. I have 2 questions please: 1. So the problem was that I used inner join looking for the match between Match_Next and MyTest, instead you look for the match between Match_Results and MyTest. What exactly is the explanation why with Match_Results it works correctly and with Match_Next it didn't work?

Comment: 2. I read that you also use "and Match_Results.away_club = MyTest.away_club", so it means that with Inner Join you look for 2 matches (home_club and away_club). If I just write ON Match_Results.home_club = MyTest.home_club (and not also that of away_club), does the code work correctly in the same way?

Comment: If you just write ON Match_Results.home_club = MyTest.home_club (and not also that of away_club), does the code work correctly in the same way? - No, code will not work correctly.

Comment: I can't understand one thing: why if you DON'T use the second condition do you get matches that both repeat? (i.e. 4 records and not 2)

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. I want to review and reflect your code better tomorrow, because I'm tired of sleep and I'm not very clear. Thanks for your help. Until tomorrow

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer. You've been kind. I still want to study the code of your answer carefully (I'm new to Python and SQL) and make sure everything is ok. In a few days I will accept your answer. Don't worry, you won't forget me. Just as I remembered to vote for your answer, I will remember to accept it. In the meantime I voted for your answer